# How to test an express.js ErrorHandler?

Tags: typescript, express, sinon

I'm trying to test the fail case for this function with TypeScript and Sinon, but I have not idea how. Any help?

```
 public async findById(id: number): Promise<UserModel> {
    const user = await this._userModel.findByPk(id);
    if (!user) throw new NotFound('User not found');
    return user;
  }
```

Comment: You describe it as an Express error handler, so presumably something like: make a request with an ID that doesn't exist, assert on the 404 status of the response.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out and end up creating a unit and integration test:

Integration:

```
it('should fail to find user by id', async function () {
   Sinon.stub(Model, 'findByPk').resolves(null);
   const response = await chai.request(app).get('/users/999').send({
     params: 999,
   });

   expect(response.status).to.equal(404);
});
```

Unit:

```
it('should fail to find user by id', async function () {
  sinon.stub(Model, 'findByPk').resolves(null);

  try {
    await userService.findById(999);
  } catch (e) {
    const error = e as Error;
    expect(error).to.be.instanceOf(NotFound);
    expect(error.message).to.equal('User not found');
  }
});
```